# Write to a JSON file on a server from flash builder

Tags: json, datagrid, flex4, flash-builder

I have a simple DataGrid that gets the Data from a JSON file hosted on a server.
I am using the build Data Connection Wizard and it works great.
Now I want to let the user manipulate the data and send it back to the JSON file.
I tried to add a form to the data grid but it changes only the data on the application and it is not influencing the file on the server.

any help or direction how should i do that will be appreciated.

Shani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i finally used
AMFphp  and wrote my own functions.